# how to open specific section in window on button click in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

I want to open a window on button click from another window and go to specific tab in that window. Let's say new window (tabsWindow) has 3 tabs - tab1, tab2 and tab3 and I have 3 buttons on main window (buttonsWindow) btn1, btn2 and btn3. All three tabs are on one window and all three buttons are on another window. On click of btn1, tab1 should be opened from tabsWindow. On btn2_Click, tab2 should open. I have heard of RoutedCommand but not good in it. Suggest me any other possible or simpler way.

Comment: I recommend you reword your question. Go to section has no meaning. There's no such thing as a section in wpf. If they're tabs then you need to select a tab. If they're not, then what's that stuff about tabs. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve from your description so I would think your question is very likely going to get closed.

Comment: How is your app built? Mvvm so a viewmodel would drive selecteditem or not - do you for example hard code 3 tab item content in tabswindow?

Comment: Yes tab items are hardcoded. Yes it is MVVM.

Comment: Since you're not binding the itemssource of the tabcontrol. Add a method on your tabswindow takes an int. Use that to set selectedindex on the tabcontrol. Pass that from the buttons. Or overload the ctor on tabswindow similarly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a toy sample by using MVVM pattern.
You can see full source in **[GitHub](https://github.com/devncore/community/tree/main/stackoverflow/answers/tabcontrol-binding-example)**.

#### ButtonsWindow.xaml

I used **`Command`** and handed over the `Button` object to the **`CommandParameter`** to specify the **SelectedIndex** of `TabControl` using the **Content of the `Button`**.

```xml
<UniformGrid Columns="3">
    <Button Margin="50" Content="1" Command="{Binding BtnClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Button Margin="50" Content="2" Command="{Binding BtnClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Button Margin="50" Content="3" Command="{Binding BtnClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

#### TabsWindow.xaml

```xml
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tab" Width="300" Height="300">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Tab1" FontSize="20" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Tab2" FontSize="20" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab3">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Tab3" FontSize="20" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

#### TabsWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class TabsWindow : Window
{
    public TabsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal void SetTab(string content)
    {
        tab.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(content) - 1;
    }
}
```

#### MainViewModel.cs

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    private TabsWindow win;
    public ICommand BtnClick { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        BtnClick = new RelayCommand<object>(Click);
    }

    private void Click(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Button btn)
        {
            if (win is null || !win.IsVisible)
            { 
                win = new TabsWindow();
                win.Show();
            }
            win.SetTab(btn.Content.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When `Button` is clicked, `TabsWindow` is activated and moves to a specific tab according to the `Content` of the `Button`. Also, if `TabsWindow` is already activated, tab can be moved without showing a new `TabsWindow`.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this code but it did not work for me.

Comment: @akilesh I've tried it again, but it works. Have you tried full source in github? Tell me specifically what part didn't work.

Comment: hey @elena.kim it worked. i took entire code from github. thanks

Comment: i want to improvise it. can you help? @elena.kim

Comment: @akilesh How about writing a new question, and put that link in this comment? I will take a look.